# get value inside textbox dojo widget at run time

Tags: events, textbox, dojo, onchange

I am using dijit.form.TextBox in my project and I want to get the run time value being changed  inside textbox for using at some other place(in grid). When I use onChange event I get the old value inside that textbox (and not the value I am editing at run time) and when I use onKeyUp event then also I get old value inside that textbox.

Can you please suggest me the way that whenever I try to edit the value it should fire some event and I should be able to get the value inside the box at that point of time and not the old value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this.

HTML

```
    <input dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox" id="myTextbox" />
```

SCRIPT

```
    dojo.connect(dijit.byId('myTextbox'),'onKeyUp',function(){
           console.log(dijit.byId('myTextbox').getValue());
    });
```

dijit.byId('myTextbox').getValue() does get me the latest value in the textbox on every keyup.

Answer (score 4):

You can also set the intermediateChanges property to true. This will make onChange fire on every change, not just when the input field is blurred.

Comment: I found this to be the better solution to the problem. I didn't test the other suggestion by Sheldon because it would've required some awkward extra coding in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays (Dojo 1.9.3) you have use the `.get("value");` property.